# How to get line number of specific line in history revisions?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

How to get line number of specific line in history revisions?

For example, I have

> > revision 123: line 77: doSomething()

in current version(revision 123) of code file.

I want do know WHERE was this line in previous version of code.
For the previous line of code, I want get its line information in revision 121

> > revision 121: line 71: doSomething()

How to do this in svn(and in git)?

---To be more specific---

My purpose is get history of revisionNo-lineNo of some code, build some function to satisfy query like:

> > Where is Line 77 in Rev.123 of XXX.java in Rev.121=>Line 71.
> >
> > Where is Line 123(new in r123) in Rev.123 of XXX.java in Rev.121=>New
> >
> > Where is Line 9999(not exist in r123) in Rev.123 of XXX.java in Rev.121=>NotExist

Comment: If your purpose is to find which commit/revision has introduced a change, you can use `git blame` or `svn blame` commands.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think svn and git have this builtin, but you can use a tool like grep to find out.

In svn (where ${reva} and ${revb} are the revisions and ${file} is the file):

```
$ svn cat -r ${reva} ${file} | grep -n doSomething
19:void doSomething()

$ svn cat -r ${revb} ${file} | grep -n doSomething
49:void doSomething()
```

In git:

```
$ git show ${reva}:${file} | grep -n doSomething
19:void doSomething()

$ git show ${revb}:${file} | grep -n doSomething
49:void doSomething()
```